# Does my PHP project need appengine-web.xml

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-php, google-cloud-tools

Setting up IntelliJ IDEA to run my PHP Wordpress (for App Engine) projects. Google Cloud Tools installed.

Have imported existing project files and then went to **Tools > Google Cloud Tools > Run on a local App Engine Standard dev server**.

An error is returned:

*Project does not contain App Engine Standard modules: To use the App Engine Standard local development server, the project must contain at least one App Engine Standard module with an `appengine-web.xml` configuration file.*

I read up on `appengine-web.xml` and apparently its used for Java projects. I'm trying to run PHP at the moment.

I haven't dealt with this file type before, is it similar to `app.yaml`?

Do I need this fie to set up my local server for PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the file [appengine-web.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref) corresponds to the App Engine Java runtime, you don't need to use it in your PHP project. It is similar to the `app.yaml` in the sense that it is where you define your default service.

In order to define the default service in your PHP app, you need the [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/configuration-files#the_default_service). There are also [optional configuration files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/configuration-files#optional_configuration_files), such as:

```
dispatch.yaml, queue.yaml, index.yaml, cron.yaml, dos.yaml
```

On a side note, maybe [PHP Storm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) or Eclipse with the [PHP Development tools](https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) are more suitable for your use case.